# how to change date format(time zone) in CDE Dashboard in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration

The data source which the date is stored in GMT is linked with Pentaho. when i am creating CDE Dashboard, i am unable to find the option changing data format into IST(GMT, +5:30:00). Let me know where to change the data format(layout Panel or components panel or datasource panel). i want the final report in IST data.